# Submit dynamically added forms

Tags: javascript

I created a form with hidden inputs for each product as add to favorites button, but when I click the button, the first product is added to the wishlist, not the clicked one.

```
<form method="POST" class="fav-form"action="favourites-add.php">
   <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="<? print $fch[id]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="owner_id" name="owner_id" value="<? print $fch[owner_id]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="client_id" name="client_id" value="<? print $_SESSION["owner_id"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="p_name" name="p_name" value="<? print $fch[p_name]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="<? print $fch[price]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="details" name="details" value="<? print $fch[details]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="region" name="details" value="<? print $fch[region]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="photo" name="photo" value="<? print $fch[photo]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="photo2" name="photo2" value="<? print $fch[photo2]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="photo3"  name="photo3" value="<? print $fch[photo3]; ?>">
   <button id="add" class="add-favourites" onclick="SubmitFormData();" type="button"><li class="far fa-star"></li></button>
</form>
```

---

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var product_id = $("#product_id").val();
    var owner_id = $("#owner_id").val();
    var client_id = $("#client_id").val();
    var p_name = $("#p_name").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var details = $("#details").val();
    var region = $("#region").val();
    var photo = $("#photo").val();
    var photo2 = $("#photo2").val();
    var photo3 = $("#photo3").val();

    $.post("favourites-add.php", {id:id, product_id: product_id, owner_id: owner_id, client_id: client_id, p_name: p_name,price: price,details: details, region: region, photo: photo, photo2: photo2, photo3: photo3, },
    function(data) {
        $('#fav').show();
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you should change the id values. But it would be a lot easier for us if you would show us the other forms/products.

Comment: the products added dynamically by php when seller add product so all products have the same form but values for hidden inputs are changing

Answer (score 0):

## IDs must be unique

If you have multiple forms which are identical, you still can't recycle `id` attributes between them. They must be unique.

## Intrinsic event attributes are horrible and not helping.

Stop using `<button id="add" class="add-favourites" onclick="SubmitFormData();" type="button"><li class="far fa-star"></li></button>`.

Use a submit button instead.

- No `onclick` attribute.
- `type="submit"`

The bind JavaScript:

```
jQuery("form").on("submit", submitFormData);
```

(Note that it is convention in JS to start function names with capital letters only if they are Constructor functions, so don't do that for your function here).

## Don't do regular submission and Ajax

Since you are now triggering the JS on the form submission you need to explicitly stop the normal form submission from happening.

```
function submitFormData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

## Pay attention to which form you are dealing with

This is why we switched to this approach:

```
function submitFormData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
}
```

## Get the data out of that form

Now, you could use `jQuery(form).find("[name='fieldName']).val()` for each value… but jQuery provides a simpler way.

```
function submitFormData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    var data = jQuery(form).serialize();
}
```

## Then submit that data

```
function submitFormData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    var data = jQuery(form).serialize();
    $.post("favourites-add.php", data);
}
```